# Trying to create a custom meta table for working with a custom table

Tags: database

I'm trying to create a custom meta table, that uses the functionality already written into WP.

```
function get_mytype_meta( $post_id, $key = '', $single = false ) {
    return get_metadata( 'mytype', $post_id, $key, $single );
}

function add_mytype_meta( $sid, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique = false ) {
    return add_metadata( 'mytype', $sid, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique );
}

function update_mytype_meta( $sid, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value = '' ) {
    return update_metadata( 'mytype', $sid, $meta_key, $meta_value, $prev_value );
}
```

What is stopping this from working so far, is the function _get_meta_table which then requires the table {wpdb->prefix}mytypemeta to be listed in $wpdb already.  I'm not sure where to do that.

Please advise.  Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer by just digging through wp-includes/meta.php ...  I just had to add to $wpdb myself at runtime.

```
add_action('init', function(){
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->mytypemeta = "{$wpdb->prefix}mytypemeta";
});
```